# Таблица на форме с чекбоксами и картинками

Tags: 1с

[image]

Как сделать такую форму, а точнее список слева с картинками и чекбоксами? Список значений формируется по табличной части в справочнике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо создать дополнительную форму и передавать в нее сформированный список значений, как параметр.

Основная форма, реквизит Т - тип ТаблицаЗначений:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура КомандаОткрытьСписокЗначений(Команда)

    С = Новый СписокЗначений;
    Для Каждого Стр Из Т Цикл
        С.Добавить(Стр.Контекст,, Истина, БиблиотекаКартинок.АктивныеПользователи);
    КонецЦикла;

    ОткрытьФорму("ВнешняяОбработка.ТестСписок.Форма.ФормаСписка", Новый Структура("СП", С), ЭтаФорма,,,,, РежимОткрытияОкнаФормы.БлокироватьОкноВладельца);

КонецПроцедуры
```

Дополнительная форма, реквизит СП - тип СписокЗначений:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ПриСозданииНаСервере(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка)

    СП = Параметры.СП;

КонецПроцедуры
```